# UILabel height not change in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c

I called function changeQuestionLabelHeight in `viewWillAppear` but the height just don't change. However, during running, it change when in portrait position as you can see the code.

Below is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self changeQuestionLabelHeight];

    self.labelQuestion.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    CGFloat fontSize = self.labelQuestion.font.pointSize;
    self.labelQuestion.minimumScaleFactor = 8.0/fontSize;
    self.labelQuestion.numberOfLines = 0;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:)
     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
     object:nil];

}

- (void)deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification*)note
{

    [self changeQuestionLabelHeight];

}

- (void) changeQuestionLabelHeight{

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    CGRect newFrame = self.labelQuestion.frame;

    switch (orientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            newFrame.size.height = self.labelQuestion.frame.size.height + 250;
            self.labelQuestion.frame = newFrame;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            newFrame.size.height = self.labelQuestion.frame.size.height + 250;
            self.labelQuestion.frame = newFrame;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Example once the viewController loaded:

[image]

After loaded and I rotated iPad to landscape:

[image]

then I rotated to portrait again:

[image]

the label setting is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same problem. Try calling any label height changes in `viewDidAppear`. Every other lifecycle method seems to be called too early.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `viewDidLayoutSubview:`

It is called every time you rotate your device

Edit:

I suggest you look up NSLayoutConstraints.
This is the constraints I used. (Auto generated by xcode)
Note: I didn't take the time to fix the buttons. They are a little screwed.

Also, I set the UILabel's number of lines to 0, and the Line breaks to word wrap.

[image: Constraints]

[image: First]
[image: Second]
[image: Third]

Comment: I changed to word wrap and part of the text ("great today") disappeared.

Comment: Did you also change number of lines to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Delete all of that code and use something like:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    CGRect newFrame = self.labelQuestion.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = 250;
    self.labelQuestion.frame = newFrame;
}
```

If you need to do anything orientation-specific during layout, you can check `self.interfaceOrientation`

Comment: where does the label's frame get set for the first time?

Comment: the label's frame is always on top as you can see the first picture but the height of it is lesser that is why I want to add 250 more to it to make it fill up unused space. Once it fill up unused space, it will look like 3rd picture above.

Answer (score -1):

oh yeah ..... finally I got it fix babe. 
All you need to do is click on the label and select Editor -> Pin -> Bottom Space to Superview and voila !! I figured out this solution While showering with my girl at her apartment.

Hope this answer will help someone facing the same issue.

Cheers,
Mark Thien